# dup2 in child persistent to parent

Tags: c, dup2

I have a weird issue with a server written in C.

I have a function that is treating each client that connects to my server, so this function calls a fork() for each connection that the server receives.

The issue is that I have other forks inside that `client-fork` that are supposed to write an `exec()`'s output inside a file that I created .I `dup2()` that file's descriptor with stdout so that the output can be read from the file inside the parent right after the second child process (the one with `exec()` call) dies.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define PORT 2021

extern int errno;

void signal_handler( int sig )
{
  printf("[Server]Cought signal SIGCHLD\n");
  while( waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0 )
    {
    }
}

int TreatClient(int clientSocket, int nr)
{
    int pid1,wait1;
    if ((pid1 = fork()) == -1)
    {
        printf("eroare pid");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid1 == 0) // treat client 
    {
        printf("START TREAT CLIENT!\n");
        nr++;
        int saved_stdout;
        char filename[3];
        snprintf(filename, 3,"%d",nr);
        int pid2,wait2;
        saved_stdout = dup(1);
        if ((pid2 = fork()) == -1)
        {
            printf("eroare pid");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid2 == 0)
        {
            printf("START DUP child!\n");
            int fd = open("fisier",O_CREAT|O_RDWR,00700);
            dup2(fd,1);
            printf("child 2 !\n");
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int fil;
            char chara;
            wait(&wait2);
            dup2(saved_stdout,1);
            close(saved_stdout);
            fil = open("fisier",O_RDONLY,00700);
            while(read(fil,&chara,1)!=-1 && chara != '\n')              printf("%c",chara);
            printf("\nEND PARENT dup !\n");
        }
        printf("TREAT CLIENT END!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&wait1);
        printf("END MAIN!\n");
    }
    return 1;
    }               /* while */
  return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
  struct sockaddr_in server;    
  struct sockaddr_in from;  
  char msg[100];        
  char rply[100]=" ";        
  int sd;           
  int on, status, nr = 0;

  if( signal(SIGCHLD, signal_handler) < 0 )
    {
      printf("[Server]Signal Error : %d !\n", errno);
      exit(-5);
    }

  if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
      perror ("[server]Socket Error !\n");
      return errno;
    }

  on = 1;
  status = setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *) &on, sizeof(on));

  if ( status == -1 )
    {
      printf("[server]Setsockopt() Error : %d !\n", errno);
      exit(-1);
    }

  bzero (&server, sizeof (server));
  bzero (&from, sizeof (from));

    server.sin_family = AF_INET;    
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
    server.sin_port = htons (PORT);

  if (bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
      printf("[server]Bind Error : %d!\n", errno);
      exit(-2);
    }

  if (listen (sd, 5) == -1)
    {
      printf ("[server]Listen Error : %d!\n", errno);
      exit(-3);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /* client-iteration*/
  while (1)
    {
      int client;
      int length = sizeof (from);

      printf ("[server]Waiting at port %d...\n",PORT);
      fflush (stdout);

      client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);
      nr++;

      if (client < 0)
    {
      printf ("[server]Accept Error : %d!\n", errno);
      continue;
    }

      printf("[server]Client number %d connected\n", nr);
      TreatClient(client, nr);
      return 1;
}
```

The desired output is simmilar to this :

```
[server]Waiting at port 2021...
[server]Client number 1 connected
START TREAT CLIENT!
START DUP child!
[Server]Cought signal SIGCHLD
child 2 !
END PARENT dup !
TREAT CLIENT END!
[Server]Cought signal SIGCHLD
END MAIN!
```

The code does not produce the desired output. It becomes stuck after DUP2 and the rest of the output is redirected towards the file. But if i replace the `TreatClient(client, nr);` line with the function block the code works as it should. Why is this happening ? Another weird issue is that the message `[server]Waiting at port 2021...` is also printed in the file and not on the screen .

Comment: `char filename[3];` 3 might be a bit too small

Comment: @wildplasser no that part works fine each client has a number by the order of arrival (1,2...) and each client will have his own file for those commands.

Comment: A mutex is used to sync threads. I don't think they work with subprocesses.

Comment: @Krumelur http://dev.yorhel.nl/doc/sqlaccess source. And i don't think that is an issue to my dup2 issue

Comment: After 100 messages you will overflow the string, and it is very dangerous not to use the same length in snprintf.

Comment: Well, in that case `snprintf(filename, 10, ...)` should have been `snprintf(filename, 3,...`

Comment: @Krumelur i won't get anywhere near to 100 messages this is just a very small project (college) and it's not aimed for enterprise or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, but you are not creating threads, you are forking. From Sqlite FAQ: "Under Unix, you should not carry an open SQLite database across a fork() system call into the child process. Problems will result if you do."

Comment: @Krumelur thanks noted but it has no effecto n my dup2 issue

Comment: Why you snprintf() with size 10 to char [3]? That might not be your current problem, but do matter.

Comment: @moeCake corrected the snprintf

Comment: Well, you wrote it was crashing.

Comment: @Krumelur check the update code, it acts the same after i eliminate any trace of sqlite stuff and i corrected the snprintf

Comment: Why is the second child returning instead of exiting?  return will have very different semantics when you move the code block into a function.

Comment: @WilliamPursell this was the issue thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the second child is finished, it should `exit` instead of returning.

Comment: Could you explain a little why return messes up the child process behavior ?

Comment: It's hard to see exactly what happens because the code in the question doesn't compile. It has mismatched braces.

Comment: @Edeph  When the 2nd child returns, it continues executing code in the caller.  The process that is `wait`ing for it to exit probably hangs since it does not exit, but as @Wumpus points out it's hard to say exactly what happens without more code.